# Switched capacitors using MOSFETs in filter design

Tags: capacitor, mosfet, filter, switching

I'm designing a State Variable Filter design using switched capacitors to control cut-off and resonance. Simulating this using idealized switches yields excellent results. See attached schematic [image: Filter design with idealized switches]

After that I proceeded to replace one of the integrators with a MOSFET version (the center-right part of the circuit). This doesn't work. I'm using a parasitic-insensitive switched cap implementation as you can see. See attached schematic [image: Filter design with 1 integrator using MOSFETS]

I tried a couple of implementations for the switches. First of all the parasitic sensitive version, and after that several parasitic-insensitive versions like this one. I've also tried several different NMOS models.

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Why did you switch it from parasitic sensitive topology to parasitic insensitive topology? Also, you have V+ and V- giving a 24 voltage difference, while your mosfets are driven by only 3 volts. I assume the signal output swings through that range, that would prevent your signal from passing through the mosfet like a switch.

Comment: @horta I switched to parasitic insensitive because the sensitive version changes the integrator response. The filter still works but cutoff is lowered a lot. Indeed the clock signal needs a wider range.. quite logical!

Comment: If the cutoff got lowered, then you probably have your MOSFET gate capacitances to thank for that. Check the model of the MOSFETs you're using and ensure that the gate-drain and gate-source capacitance isn't negatively affecting your filter.

Comment: Add clock waveforms to your post, connect your NMOS Bulk connections properly (to ground), make sure you have NOC (Non-overlapped clocks) - especially the complements, increase voltage swing on gates

Comment: What is the modification? Why don`t you answer our questions?

Comment: I abandoned this design in favour of an OTA-based SVF. Haven't looked at it in a long time. But thanks for everybody's replies.

Answer (score 2):

"*Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong here*?"

Yes - I am afraid you didn´t realize that in the second circuit (MOSFET realization) the capacitor C2 now is operated with phase inversion. That means: The most right opamp now is operating as a non-inverting integrator (besides all other effects as mentioned already).

As a result - you have positive feedback, in contrast to the first circuit (with idealized switches and another S/C realization). You can cure the situation by modifying the clock sequence for two switches.

Comment: Pieter - did you understand my above recommendation? You have produced a phase inversion around C2.